# Android storing image and view it in gallery

Tags: android, android-image

I am storing image from an `imageView` which is available as `bitmap`.

I am storing the image as `test.jpg` in the external memory although the image gets saved by that name (I confirmed by using a file manager in phone) the image is not presented in the gallery where all other images are shown.

Why is this so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

media rescan is normally done on reboot.

you need to trigger it manual to get the new file to be include in gallery.

read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) how to manual rescan so it show up

Comment: thanks for the help i will try it. Sorry though don't have enough points (15req) to vote you up.

Comment: u can accept an answer even tho u have no points